# 503 response after sending first chunk of Google Docs resumable upload using cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I have a PHP application that provides some Google Docs integration to users, and I'm trying to add the ability to upload files directly into the user's Docs account (I'm rolling my own using PHP/cURL since my requirements are simple and I don't want to mess with Zend Framework just for this one feature).

I'm following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_content_only and
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/resumable_upload, and things seem to be working OK until I try to send the second chunk, at which point I always receive a 503 Service Unavailable response from the server.

Here's the full sequence of events:

1) I send a POST with the following headers to the upload URI:

```
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: Bearer (token removed for security reasons, but it's there and correct)
Content-Length: 0
Slug: gmk_google_upload_test.txt
X-Upload-Content-Type: text/plain
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2652
```

The server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 30 2012 11:18:04 (1343672284)
Location: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false&upload_id=AEnB2Uoa4ba2XrKG58GU3uTSzKUKsQu_NfOUvyYDqW6iXwmHgBPiJsi1fg-RhxMVT7jAfd1o73fUtBaaZ1uLkwNwzT04NxQbuQ
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 16:00:13 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So far, so good.

2) I PUT the first chunk (512 bytes) to the URL from the response, using these headers:

```
Host: docs.google.com
Content-Length: 512
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Range: bytes 0-511/2652
```

Server Responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 308 Resume Incomplete
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 30 2012 11:18:04 (1343672284)
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 16:00:14 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This may be the start of my problem, since I don't receive a Range header back from the server as described in the documentation. However, it seems like something must be working for me to get the 308 Resume Incomplete response.

3) When I send the next chunk using the (I think) correct headers and range information for the next chunk:

```
Host: docs.google.com
Content-Length: 512
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Range: bytes 512-1023/2652
```

I always get this response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 30 2012 11:18:04 (1343672284)
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2012 16:00:14 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I've tried different types of files, chunk sizes, etc., but I always get the same result. Strangely, if I send a request to try to get the number of bytes that have been received by the server (per the documentation links above):

```
PUT <upload_uri> HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes */100
```

I get a 308 Resume Incomplete response (as expected), but still no Range header. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid somewhere, but I've been banging my head against the wall long enough that I can't see it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but am not able to switch to the newer API. Did you manage to solve this issue in the end?

Comment: Was this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the newer Drive API? 
The [PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) is not based on the Zend Framework and the documentation includes [snippets](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) and a [complete PHP sample application](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php).

If you still want to implement the resumable upload protocol yourself, you should take a look at how it is supported in newer APIs, including the the Google Drive API:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: Thanks @Claudio -- I will give the Google Drive API a try. I'd still like to figure out what's going wrong here, as I have a feeling I might run into the same issue with Google Drive (the mechanism looks similar), but we shall see :).

Answer (score 2):

Just solved the same problem with `Google drive`.

```
set size chunk = 256 * 1024
```